# Get retry history in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using the BigQuery API in Python and I implemented a retry in Bigquery using this (https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/retry.html). I'd like to know if there is a way for me to know when queries encountered an error and had been successfully retried?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has an `on_error` parameter. Try passing some logging function into it.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks! Not sure how I missed that though.